# Why does TypeScript require me to use a conditional statement with two identical branches?

Tags: typescript, types

Consider the below TypeScript code:

```
type StringToVoidOrNumsPromise = (arg0: string) => void | Promise<number[]>;

const goodFunc = (sourceFunction: StringToVoidOrNumsPromise): StringToVoidOrNumsPromise => {
    const copiedFunction: StringToVoidOrNumsPromise = async (input: string) => {
        const oldResult = await sourceFunction(input);
        if (oldResult instanceof Promise) {
            return oldResult;
        } else {
            return oldResult;
        }
    };
    return copiedFunction;
};

const badFunc = (sourceFunction: StringToVoidOrNumsPromise): StringToVoidOrNumsPromise => {
    const copiedFunction: StringToVoidOrNumsPromise = async (input: string) => {
        const oldResult = await sourceFunction(input);
        return oldResult;
    };
    return copiedFunction;
};
```

The two functions seem like they should be identical, but goodFunc is fine, while badFunc gives me a static type error:

```
Type '(input: string) => Promise<void | number[]>' is not assignable to type 'StringToVoidOrNumsPromise'.
  Type 'Promise<void | number[]>' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise<number[]>'.
    Type 'Promise<void | number[]>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<number[]>'.
      Type 'void | number[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
        Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.ts(2322)
```

What's going on here?

Comment: The goodFunc works for the wrong reason. The badFunc errors for the right reason. You're returning `Promise<void | number[]>` in `badFunc`, which isn't assignable to `void | Promise<number[]>`. You should either edit the type to `Promise<void | number[]>` or correct the badFunc: https://tsplay.dev/mA2oPW

Comment: But why is the type I'm returning in badFunc different from the type I'm returning in goodFunc?

Comment: Hover over the function name and `oldResult` in the return statements. It's clearly different.

Comment: @fblundun `badFunc` only ever returns a promise. It can't return anything else. `StringToVoidOrNumsPromise` itself has a very odd definition requiring *either* void *or* a promise.

Comment: @kelsny but why is the behaviour for goodFunc different?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is `async` meaning it can only return `Promise<any>` and any `T` value you return will be wrapped into a `Promise<T>`

That means you return value is `Promise<number[] | void>` making your function not assignable to `(...) => Promise<number[]> | void`

```
const goodFunc = (sourceFunction: StringToVoidOrNumsPromise): StringToVoidOrNumsPromise => {
  const copiedFunction: StringToVoidOrNumsPromise = (input: string) => {
    const oldResult = sourceFunction(input);
    if (oldResult instanceof Promise) {
      return oldResult.then(e => e);
    } else {
      return // oldResult; // it's void
    }
  };
  return copiedFunction;
};
```